# vision_opencv installation error on beagleboard

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ubuntu-oneiric, vision-opencv, beagleboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey

I was trying to install vision_opencv from here:

```
https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vision_opencv/
```

on my BeagleBoard xM running Oneiric.

Each time i perform

```
rosdep install vision_opencv
```

I get an error saying: unable to find ros-fuerte-opencv2.
I checked the Makefile and it says to look for ros-fuerte-opencv2 in the apt-repository, but since we don't really have a ros repository for BeagleBoard and the installation has to be done from source, i dont really know how to install this package.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38194/vision_opencv-installation-error-on-beagleboard/) by [incognito](https://answers.ros.org/users/2784/incognito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2012-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The source installation is the only way to install something on an ARM Platform but after a while is pretty straightforward:

first checkout the source code

```
$ svn checkout https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vision_opencv/trunk
```

then create a build dir and go into it

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
```

then make it with cmake

```
$ cmake ..
```

then make and install

```
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

hope I could help.

---

Originally posted by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) with karma: 447 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0